# How to set cursor in new text areas?

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, jtextarea

I have a program that creates a new text area on a `JFrame` where ever I left click. However, I always need to click the text area again in order to move the cursor there to type.

I was wondering how I could automatically set the cursor in the text area each time I create a new one without having to click again. How to set cursor in new text areas?

Comment: Oracle has a tutorial on the focus subsystem:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Comment: [`requestFocusInWindow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow--)..

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: @noone `Thanks it worked!` - then don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) has suggested:

You should use the following method in order to set the cursor in new text areas (note the link to docs.oracle.com) - 
[requestFocusInWindow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow--)

Comment: (1+) I also agree questions should have answers so the OP can "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so everybody knows the problem has beensolved.

Comment: @camickr : RFE in the making.

Comment: Thanks for having the fortitude to turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : My pleasure. The credit should go to you of course. A comment/answer feature would be the appropriate thing.

Comment: Your answer was complete donkey flexes

Comment: That’s a compliment